# How to copy a file from my home folder to /usr

Tags: permissions

I'm trying to copy a file from my homedir to /usr. How do I setup the permissions to allow this?

```
$ chmod 777 KeePass-2.14.zip
$ cp KeePass-2.14.zip /usr/keepass/
cp: cannot create regular file `/usr/keepass/KeePass-2.14.zip': Permission denied
$ sudo cp KeePass-2.14.zip /usr/keepass/
cp: cannot stat `KeePass-2.14.zip': Permission denied
$
```

Comment: Can you paste the line in `/etc/sudoers` that allows your user to `sudo`? It should be something like `phunehehe ALL=(ALL) ALL`...

Comment: Perhaps you could first tell us why you are trying to copy this file to `/usr`? Seems like an unusual thing to do. If you are trying to unpack for an install, that is the wrong place to put it in. Something like `/usr/local/src` would be better. At least, that is what  I use. Is there no binary package available for `keepass` for your OS?

Comment: @Faheem - why /.../src? Why not /usr/local? I haven't memorized the folder structure yet, I just want somewhere to put it (looking for the equivalent of C:\Program Files).

Comment: `/usr/local/src` is customary, I believe. The FHS says "/usr/local/src: Local source code". See http://www.pathname.com/fhs/pub/fhs-2.3.html#USRLOCALLOCALHIERARCHY

Answer (score 19, accepted):

I'm guessing that  `sudo cp` can't stat `KeePass-2.14.zip` because `$HOME` is on an NFS mount, and the NFS server doesn't grant your machine root permission to the NFS share.

Try:

```
cp KeePass-2.14.zip /tmp
sudo cp /tmp/KeePass-2.14.zip /usr/keepass/
```

Answer (score 0):

To answer the original question, I would adjust the permissions after the event. Just copy the file across (doesn't really matter with what permissions) and then change the permissions to match the place where you are copying it to. But in this case, I doubt that what you are trying to do is what you really want to do.

Answer (score -1):

Change permission on directory `/usr/keepass` to 777 and then `cp` the files to `/usr/keepass/`

Comment: How does `777` help when `sudo cp ...` doesn't work?

Comment: True. But he didn't provide information about permissions on `/usr/keepass`. Also he might has limited `sudo` rights.

Comment: I have nothing against your answer (I didn't downvote, in case you are suspecting that). I just think that you can add a little bit more to it.

Comment: Yes, another mystery down-voter strikes again. (on several levels) ..... WHY!??? ..... ;-)

Comment: @powerwade: the error message that he gets when he uses sudo isn't what you'd see if you had limited `sudo` rights.

Comment: I've checked that later, you're right. I should check it before i advise next time. :)

Comment: This actually helped me with my related problem of folders getting copied over with permissions and everything lol